# Modelica vector parameters from a file

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

Is it possible to read a vector of parameters from a file? 
I'm trying to create a vector of objects, such as shown here:  [enter link description here](https://modelica.org/events/Conference2003/Modelica03-AdvancedTutorial.pdf) starting on page 49.  However, I would like to pull the specific resistance and capacitance values from a text file.  (I'm actually just using this as an example for how to read it in).
So,  the example fills in data like this:

```
A.Basic.Resistor  R[N + 1](R = vector([Re/2; fill(Re,N-1); Re/2]) );
A.Basic.Capacitor C[N](each C = c*L/N);
```

But, instead I have a text file that contains something like, where the first column is the index, the second is the R values and the third is the C values:

```
#1
double test1(4,3)   #First set of data (row then col)
1.0 1.0 10.0
2.0 2.0 30.0
3.0 5.0 50.0
4.0 7.0 100.0
```

I know that I can read this data in using a CombiTable1D or CombiTable2D. But, is there a way to  essentially convert each column of data to a vector so that I can do something analogous to:

```
ReadInTableFromDisk
A.Basic.Resistor  R[N + 1](R = FirstDataColumnOfDataOnDisk );
A.Basic.Capacitor C[N](each C = SecondDataColumnOfDataOnDisk);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the **ExternData** library if you want to load external data files into your modelica tool.

[Modelica library for data I/O of INI, JSON, XML, MATLAB MAT and Excel XLS/XLSX files](https://github.com/tbeu/ExternData)

Comment: It looks that that library is not yet working with OpenModelica.  At least, all of the Examples fail with errors. There have been a bunch of commits to that library in OM, so my guess is that it is being worked on, but isn't there yet.

Comment: Then you can take a look at the Modelica_LinearSystem2 library that usually comes with Modelica standard library. I guess you should be able to get it from OpenModelica. There are some internal functions that can help you load external .mat files.

Comment: One question about the ExternData library, were you cloning the master branch? I remembered that it was working fine with Dymola at least, and it should be compatible with OpenModelica, maybe give those released versions a try.

Comment: I was trying to use the version that was supplied with OM.  I believe that they clone the library and supply a very recent copy (they might even be patching it to try to make it work?).

Comment: I am sorry that I have no experience with OpenModelica, but I just noticed that an issue had been created this morning by the core developer (tbeu) of ExternData library. https://github.com/tbeu/ExternData/issues/9

Answer (score 0):

There is the vector() function that converts arrays to vectors.

Comment: That function is actually used in my example above, so I am aware of it.  The question is how to read data from disk as a vector (or as an array, to convert to a vector)?